# marker abnormal in istanbul coverage report in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I run unit test with Karma and generate coverage report, however, it seems the colored part, like these red colored code, got shifted abnormally like shown below:

[image]
[image]

The relevant library versions are: 
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0", 
"@angular/cli": "^6.1.1", 
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0", 
"jasmine-core": "~3.1.0", 
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1", 
"karma": "~2.0.5", 
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0", 
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1", 
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1", 
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0", 
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",

The `test.ts` is:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare const __karma__: any;
declare const require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

The `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "rubik-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "npm run i18n",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "prebuild": "npm run i18n",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run i18n",
    "icon": "node scripts/generateIconSymbol",
    "i18n": "node scripts/compileI18n",
    "test": "ng test rubik-frontend --code-coverage",
    "test:single": "ng test rubik-frontend --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix --type-check",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "echarts": "^4.0.4",
    "jsplumb": "^2.7.3",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.8",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "studio-ui": "^0.2.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

The command line I used is: 
`ng test rubik-frontend --code-coverage`

Thanks !

Comment: What command are you running exactly ? Please post your `test.ts` along with that and your `package.json` scripts. I remember resolving this issue by removing the `--source-map false` of my test command. It can also happen when your tests run into errors or exceptions.

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you for your reply. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to use

`ng test rubik-frontend --code-coverage true --source-map true`

This fixed my issue as far as I can tell. I am not sure, why it does not use source-map per default.

Comment: I had the same issue, adding `--source-map=true` to the command sorted it out. Not sure why this isn't on by default.